# Ansible ERROR! no action detected in task

Tags: python, cassandra, ansible

I am trying to run a playbook https://github.com/Datanexus/dn-cassandra

With the different deployment scenarios listed out there, I am going for multinode cassandra setup described here: [deployment scenarios](https://github.com/Datanexus/dn-cassandra/blob/master/docs/Deployment-Scenarios.md).

I have setup a static inventory file.

```
cassandra-seed-01 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.0.17 ansible_ssh_port=22 ansible_ssh_user='root' ansible_ssh_private_key_file='keys/id_rsa'
cassandra-seed-02 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.0.18 ansible_ssh_port=22 ansible_ssh_user='root' ansible_ssh_private_key_file='keys/id_rsa'
cassandra-non-seed-01 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.0.22 ansible_ssh_port=22 ansible_ssh_user='root' ansible_ssh_private_key_file='keys/id_rsa'

[cassandra_seed]
192.168.0.17
192.168.0.18

[cassandra]
192.168.0.22
```

However when I try running the playbook it throws the following error:

> ERROR! no action detected in task
>
> The error appears to have been in
>   '/home/laumair/workspace/dn-cassandra/provision-cassandra.yml': line
>   21, column 9, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact
>   syntax problem.
>
> The offending line appears to be:
>
> ```
>   # then, build the seed and non-seed host groups
>   - include_role:
>     ^ here
> ```

I would appreciate any sort of direction with this error as I have tried out solutions for similar errors but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[include_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/include_role_module.html) is available since Ansible 2.2.
Please upgrade your Ansible installation.